# rsnapshot gamma and delta not running

Tags: rsnapshot

I have used rsnapshot for many years and never had an issue but I can't figure this one out. Version is 1.4.2.

I have the following in rsnapshot.conf:

```
retain  alpha       8
retain  beta        7
retain  gamma       8
retain  delta       12
```

..and the following in crontab:

```
0 11,12,14,16,18,20 * * * /usr/bin/rsnapshot alpha
00 22 * * * /usr/bin/rsnapshot beta
30 2 * * 5 /usr/bin/rsnapshot gamma
00 6 1 * * /usr/bin/rsnapshot delta
```

The beta and alpha jobs runs perfectly:

```
root@host1:/Backup/rsnapshot_backups# ls -lt
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 30 18:06 alpha.0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 30 16:09 alpha.1
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 30 14:14 alpha.2
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 30 12:10 alpha.3
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 30 11:09 alpha.4
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 29 20:06 alpha.5
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 29 18:06 alpha.6
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 29 16:09 alpha.7
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 18:10 beta.0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 27 18:06 beta.1
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 26 18:08 beta.2
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 25 18:09 beta.3
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 24 18:12 beta.4
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 23 18:16 beta.5
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root root 4096 Oct 22 18:23 beta.6
```

However the gamma and delta never runs. What am I doing wrong?

From rsnapshot.log:

```
[2017-10-27T02:30:02] /usr/bin/rsnapshot gamma: started
[2017-10-27T02:30:02] echo 2250 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
[2017-10-27T02:30:02] /Backup/rsnapshot_backups/beta.6 not present (yet), nothing to copy
[2017-10-27T02:30:02] rm -f /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
[2017-10-27T02:30:02] /usr/bin/rsnapshot gamma: completed successfully
```

It complains about not being able to find beta.6 but I have confirmed that the directory exists.